# Schema Validation Warnings and Errors

Tags: c#, xsd

When I run the xsd tool to generate vb classes against:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="Security" type="SecurityType"/>
<xs:complexType name="SecurityType">
   <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UsernameToken" type="UsernameToken"/>
    </xs:sequence> 
    <xs:attribute name="mustUnderstand" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:anyAttribute/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="UsernameToken">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Username" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="Password"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Password">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute name="Type" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I get the following schema validation warnings:

Type Password is not declared
Type UsernameToken is not declared
Type SecurityType is not declared

I get the following Error:

The datatype 'SecurityType' is missing

Comment: Take out the `targetNamespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"` and it will work properly. Something about how you are referencing that schema must not be correct. Also, you can see those same errors if you load the XSD in Visual Studio.

Comment: Is the element closed to soon?  Shouldn't thier be a closing </xs: element> after all the complex types?

Comment: @rsbarro - I think that is it based on loading the file in Visual Studio.  The warnings went away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added `xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"` and it worked.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working. You should supply the full xsd in the answer (or at least the root element, did you also take out the targetNamespace?) in case someone else has a similar problem.

Comment: @rsbarro - The post contains the whole xsd.  I did not remove the targetNamespace.